# Storyboard Custom Class not instantiating UIView class. Why? Objective C / Xcode

Tags: objective-c, xcode, storyboard

I have a feeling I am just forgetting something stupid but I haven't been a big user of storyboards in the past.  Trying to change that.

I've got a ViewController in a storyboard which has a UIVew that I've dragged from the Object Library.  I have created a class which inherits from UIView called TopNav.  I set the class for my UIView in my storyboard to TopNav.

I'm using Xcode 6.0.

Here is my TopNav class code:

TopNav.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface TopNav : UIView

@end
```

TopNav.m

```
#import "TopNav.h"

@implementation TopNav

-(id)init {
    self = [super init];
    if (self != nil)
    {
        [self initializeUI];
    }
    return self;
}


-(void)initializeUI
{
    NSLog(@"TopNav UI initialized.");
}

@end
```

-(void)initializeUI never gets called.

I should add that when the app is running in the simulator, the ViewController containing the UIView in question is loaded properly via segue.  But there is no log for initializeUI.

What am I missing?  Do I need to do something else to instantiate the class?  Please let me know if you need more information.

Thanks!

Comment: Use `initWithCoder:` initializer when using views from storyboard.

Comment: Thanks Andy.  That was it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Needed to use initWithCoder: as Andy pointed out in his comment.  Thanks.